# How to use @solana/spl-token library in my html file with node.js code?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, spl-token, nft, phantom

I need help. I don't understand how to use the `@solana/spl-token` library so that it is available in the browser. I am writing a project related to NFT transactions from one wallet to another using Phantom and there I need to use `createTransferCheckedInstruction` function and then add it to the transaction. But how to do it? I can't use import in .js files which I then plug into my html file. Thanks

I can use such functions as `PublicKey, getbalance`, etc. because I have index.iife and index.iife.min in the project folder where the functions are located. Like this:

```
script src="js/libs/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script

script src="js/script.js"></script

script src="js/index.iife.min.js?d"></script
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

It will be hard to do this on the client side without some customization.

The main issue is that the `@solana/spl-token` package depends on libraries unavailable in the browser.

To get around this, most projects use a bundler like `webpack` to handle this case, it can work around this limitation.

Another way to get around this is to use a tool like `browserify` to create compatible files and use those.

You can find an example of this in the [McSwap](https://github.com/McDegens-DAO/McSwap/tree/main/js/web3) repo.

Comment: Is there any way I can use library through the CDN? I tried to connect the library in this way, but I get an error with exporting uuid.

Comment: No, I don't think you can use them directly from a CDN.

Either copy the ones from the McSwap into your project (at your risk) or compile them from source yourself and use those.